# How to assign a property to a value depending on the value of a different property when returning a new object C#?

Tags: c#, object, oop, return, assign

I have a project in C#. I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in one of my business logic methods I return a new object of type `MyClass`, but the problem is to set properties like `Info` or `Name` I need to call out to a different logic that gets `Info` and `Name` based on the `Id` property. However, from withing returning a new MyClass object, I can not reference a property while assigning a value to a different property, here is a code snippet with a comment of what I mean:

```
public MyClass GetNewMyClassObject(List<int> ids)
{
    return new MyClass
    {
         Id = GetCurrentId(ids),
         Info = GetInfoFromId(?),//CAN'T PASS "Id" as a parameter here, it doesnt exist 
                                 // in the context so I have
                                 //to call GetCurrentId(ids) to pass the Id to GetInfoFromId() again!
    
         Name = GetNameFromId(?)
    }
}
```

Comment: Write a real constructor? Or implement real getters for Info and Name?

Comment: Call `GetCurrentId(ids)` before the `new` of `MyClass` and assign the return to a local variable. Then use that local variable in the object initialization.

Answer (score 2):

```
public MyClass GetNewMyClassObject(List<int> ids)
{
    var id = GetCurrentId(ids);
    return new MyClass
    {
         Id = id,
         Info = GetInfoFromId(id),
         Name = GetNameFromId(id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Per my earlier comment:

Call GetCurrentId(ids) before the new of MyClass and assign the return to a local variable. Then use that local variable in the object initialization.

e.g.

```cs
public MyClass GetNewMyClassObject(List<int> ids)
{
    int id = GetCurrentId(ids);
    return new MyClass
    {
         Id = id,
         Info = GetInfoFromId(id),
         Name = GetNameFromId(id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With C# 8 [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) with a single [var pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#var-pattern) can be used to declare a shared bound variable, e.g.:

```
public MyClass GetNewMyClassObject(List<int> ids) =>
    GetCurrentId(ids) switch
    {
        var id => new MyClass
        {
            Id = id,
            Info = GetInfoFromId(id),
            Name = GetNameFromId(id)
        }
    };
```